# If $H = Z(G),$ then $Z(G/H) = 1.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples, quotient-spaces, quaternions, quotient-group

I know that this statement is false: If $H = Z(G),$ then $Z(G/H) = 1.$

And I have known from a previous question of mine that any non-abelian nilpotent group is a counterexample.

**My questions are:**

1- Why any non-abelian nilpotent group is a counterexample? what is the idea that we are using to create a counterexample?

2- Could anyone show me the details that show that the quaternions group is a counterexample, please? why is the center of the quaternions $\mathbb Z_{2}$?

Could anyone help me with that, please?

Comment: What means gp.?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Group, obviously

Comment: Adding two letters would be good then...

Comment: What are you stuck on the second question? Just compute $Z(Q)$ and $Q/Z(Q)$ for the quaternion group $Q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotients of nilpotent groups are also nilpotent, and nontrivial nilpotent groups have a nontrivial center practically by definition. For the second question, just use the fact that any group of order $4$ is abelian.

Comment: Can you show me the details please?

Comment: What details? There's not much more to say.

Comment: I know that the center of the quaternions group is $\{-1,1\}$ ...... so why it is $Z_{2}$ then?

Comment: How to calculate $Q/Z{Q}$? is it just taking the elements that are not in the center ?

Comment: How can I use the fact that any group of order 4 is abelian? what is the importance of this fact in the solution?

Comment: For the first question, $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is isomorphic to $\pm 1$. For the second questoin, are you familiar with quotient groups? The definition of nilpotence is not going to make much sense if not. For the third, what is the center of an abelian group?

Comment: The center of an abelian group is the group itself.

Comment: yes, I am familiar with quotient groups ..... I know that I should calculate the cosets ..... but how can I do that in case of quaternions?

Comment: And which definition of quaternions is easier in calculating the center?

Comment: Just choose any of them. It's a group of order 8; it's a short calcluation. Once you have $Z(Q)$, then $Q/Z(Q)$ is a group of order $4$ and thus abelian, so you're done.

Comment: So where is the contradiction? I can not see it.

Comment: Why the example should have a nilpotent group?

Comment: Are not we searching for **non-abelian** not abelian?

Comment: You should work through the construction. It's straightforward, and the only tricky bits are in the post.